# SD card or USB stick as permanent storage?

Tags: kubuntu, 19.04, storage

My internal SSD is running short on space and I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on using an SD card or USB stick as permanent storage. I have an external USB hard drive but would rather not have to carry it around. I understand that this sort of flash memory is not designed to be constantly overwritten and so I would use it as file storage only (music/photos) and it would be essentially read-only unless I add files to it on occasion. I would keep a regular backup as well. Would a high capacity SD card be feasible for something like this? If so, what filesystem should I use to ensure the maximum life of the card? Would a USB stick be of any advantage over the SD card? I don't use Windows and so compatibility with other operating systems is not an issue. Thanks!

Comment: external hard disk is also a viable option. I had been booting off of an external hard disk until I switched to internal ssd. the biggest drawback with it as primary storage is that it can get disconnected and would need to restart.

Answer (score 1):

Since you keep a regular backup using a USB stick or SD card should work until you upgrade to a bigger internal drive. If size is not an issue, I would recommend

- a high quality and fast USB 3 stick, or
- even bigger and better: a USB 3 SSD (in an external box).

See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed) about fast USB drives.

---

You can use a linux file system, ext2 or ext4. If you use ext4, you should turn off journaling. In both cases I recommend to use the mount option `noatime` in order to reduce wear. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS#Final_system_tweaks).

---

An alternative is to store your files in the cloud (there are many 'free' or cheap web sites, where you can store files and access them whereever there is an internet connection).